# Favourite a Stack Overflow Blog Article

Tags: support, bookmarks, blog

How do I favourite/star an article from the Stack Overflow blog? (Similar to how it is done for Stack Overflow questions.)

I want to add the below article to my Stack Overflow favourites:
https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/12/practical-ways-to-write-better-javascript/?cb=1

Comment: You don't. You can bookmark it in your browser.

Answer (score 5):

The blog isn't part of the Q&A site; it's an external website with a separate codebase and is just hosted on the same domain.

The blog (currently) doesn't have any feature to star/favorite posts, but it can be an interesting feature request. :)